# how to exclude specific architecture in command line xcode build

Tags: xcode, xcode12

Right now i am generating xcode build for ios-simulators via command line

which is look like this

`xcodebuild -workspace Test.xcworkspace -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release -scheme TestProd`

But for this build to get succeed  i am changing build setting in Xcode like excluding arch - **Any iOS Simulator = arm64**

can anyone help me to find correct argument for doing this in command line so i can avoid doing this manually ?

xCode Version 12.1